# Getting random N permutations of numeric array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, math, permutation, numeric

I found this function while I was looking for fastest way to find all possible permutations of numeric array.

```
private function permute(array $elements)
    {
        if (count($elements) <= 1) {
            yield $elements;
        } else {
            foreach ($this->permute(array_slice($elements, 1)) as $permutation) {
                foreach (range(0, count($elements) - 1) as $i) {
                    yield array_merge(
                        array_slice($permutation, 0, $i),
                        [$elements[0]],
                        array_slice($permutation, $i)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I need is, to shuffle it's results and get random N permutations of a numeric array.

The problem is, it returns object and it's impossible to shuffle it's result.

Any sugestions?
Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This method returns an instance of [Generator Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php). And this is predictable as it uses [`yield`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) instead of `return`. You can loop over this object with `foreach`, or in your case you, can get the whole array of permutations with [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) (this is possible because generator implements [Traversable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php)).

```
$permutations = iterator_to_array(permute($array));

shuffle($permutations);

$result = array_slice($permutations, 0, 3);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f9d909b721045d6fc652e03d897ba19d18d8279).

You can read [more about generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).